# What's that word where a company lets someone review a product but they can't say anything until a certain day?

Tags: single-word-requests

Say I'm a content-creator and I receive a product, I make all my videos but I can't release the videos until that window opens up. There's a term for that window that I can't quite remember.

Comment: The window itself, or the restriction on release?

Comment: They will be _kept under wraps_ until the rellease date.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Embargoed - I work with and around journalists and they often get media releases which begin by stating the information is embargoed until a certain time and date.